# Convert XML Data to Tabular and XML Form in SQL Server 2005

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, xquery-sql

This is my XML

```
<ROOMTYPES>
  <ROOMTYPE Id="1" Total="5">
    <ROOMFACILITIES>
      <FID>101</FID>
      <FID>103</FID>
      <FID>105</FID>
    </ROOMFACILITIES>
  </ROOMTYPE>
  <ROOMTYPE Id="2" Total="4">
    <ROOMFACILITIES>
      <FID>108</FID>
      <FID>109</FID>
      <FID>110</FID>
    </ROOMFACILITIES>
  </ROOMTYPE>
</ROOMTYPES>
```

I need to make an XQuery which would display the result like this

```
int int xml
1   5   <FID>101</FID><FID>103</FID><FID>105</FID>
2   4   <FID>108</FID><FID>109</FID><FID>110</FID>
```

I have reached here..

```
int int xml
1   5   <FID>101</FID><FID>103</FID><FID>105</FID>
2   4   <FID>101</FID><FID>103</FID><FID>105</FID>
```

using this

```
declare @xmldocument xml;
set @xmldocument =( select RoomTypes from Hotels);

declare @tb table(id int, total int, fid xml);
declare @id int;
set @id=0;
insert into @tb (id, total,fid)

select  
    p.value('../@Id', 'int'),
    p.value('../@Total', 'int'),
    p.query('//ROOMTYPE[@Id=1]/ROOMFACILITIES/FID')

from @xmldocument.nodes('ROOMTYPES/ROOMTYPE/ROOMFACILITIES') n(p)
select * from @tb;
```

Since I have hardcoded @Id=1 its showing the result of first element only.

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  
    p.value('../@Id', 'int'),
    p.value('../@Total', 'int'),
    p.query('FID')
from @xmldocument.nodes('ROOMTYPES/ROOMTYPE/ROOMFACILITIES') n(p)
```